# Any Free Alternative to the ASP.net Calendar Control?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, calendar

Here are the problems I am having with the control from the factory:

- no easy way to get the first visible date (yeah I could use day render, but at that point  in the page cycle, I can't do what I need to, which is manipulate a collection in viewstate)
- changing the visibledate property in my code does not raise the visiblemonthchanged event. That just doesn't make any sense to me.

Can someone suggest a free, improved calendar control?

Comment: The reason the event is not fired when you change VisibleDate is because the event is only fired on PostBack. You handle that event to do something when the user made a change, not you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**jQuery** [datepicker](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker):

example:

```
<input id='datepicker' class='datepicker' />

$(function(){
$(".datepicker").datepicker({ 
                          buttonImage: "/Content/img/calendar.gif", 
                          buttonImageOnly: true });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Greetings,

You could try the calender control from [http://www.eworldui.net](http://www.eworldui.net/).  I have used them without any issues and they are free to use.

Answer (score 1):

With [BaseCalendar](http://basecalendar.codeplex.com/) you can call FirstVisibleDay to get the actual first rendered day. However, BaseCalendar works differently from the built-in calendar. It gives you full control over the HTML but doesn't rely / work with PostBacks like the built-in one does.